# TypeError at / string indices must be integers

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a custom made user creation form where user can type username,password and email to register in my site. but I am unable to debug this error. What kind of type error its referring to? I am using django 2.1 and postgresql 10.3 as db.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'password'}))
    password_confirmation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'password confirmation'}))
    email = forms.EmailField()

   def clean(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    password_confirmation = self.cleaned_data.get('password_confirmation')
    print(password)
    print(password_confirmation)
    if password != password_confirmation:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Password Must Match')
    return password
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import SignUpView
urlpatterns = [
    path('',SignUpView,name = 'signup')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SignUpForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse

def SignUpView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user = User(request,username=username,email=email)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponse('User Created')
    else:
        form =SignUpForm()
    return render(request,'signup.html',{'form':form})
```

TraceBack Error

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\muvi_2\account\views.py" in SignUpView
  10.             username = form.cleaned_data['username']

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: You defined `return password` as `clean`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry cant understand!so what to write instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define the `clean` function as:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):

    # ...

    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        # ...
        return password
```

The `super(..)` however, is supposed to return the `cleaned_data`, so a dictionary. By overwriting it and returning the `password`, the "endproduct" of `form.cleaned_data` is no longer a dictionary-like object, but a string. Or like the [documentation on form-cleaning [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) specifies:

> The form subclass's `clean()` method can perform validation that requires access to multiple form fields. This is where you might put in checks such as "if field A is supplied, field B must contain a valid email address". **This method can return a completely different dictionary** if it wishes, which will be **used as the `cleaned_data`**.

So as a result, `password` will take the place of the `cleaned_data` (and it is not a dictionary-like object), so we can no longer obtain `form.cleaned_data['username']`, since `'some_password'['username']`, of course makes no sense to Python.

We can rewrite the `clean` function by returning the `self.cleaned_data` at the end (by calling the `super().clean()` function for example):

```
from django import forms

class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password_confirmation = self.cleaned_data.get('password_confirmation')
        print(password)
        print(password_confirmation)
        if password != password_confirmation:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Password Must Match')
        return super().clean()
```

**Additional error(s)**: after the form is validated, you aim to create a `User` object with:

```
user = User(request, username=username,email=email)
```

It is however not crear to me why you here use the `request` object. I think it should be:

```
user = User(username=username, email=email, password=hashed_password)
```

You will also need to *hash* the password first, since otherwise *it is a serious security threat*. See [the Django documentation on password hashing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/) for more information.

Comment: thanks sir but now its rising password must match error even if passwords are exact identical.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: can you inspect the log, you print the two passwords, so it is possible that there is still a small error. Perhaps it is even better to `print(repr(..))` here.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: I realised I made a mistakel. The reason why this will not work is because at that time, the `password_confirmation` might not be cleaned yet. You can use the `clean` function, but I would suggest calling the `super` function to obtain the "new" `cleaned_data`.

Comment: yeah sir, password confirmation is not working properly, its showing none in log.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsen Sir now its giving this error,when i am submitting the form. `TypeError at /
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'WSGIRequest'`

Comment: Can you post the *full* traceback. Please edit the question.

Comment: I think it is probably due to the `user = User(request,username=username,email=email)`, why do you add the `request` there?

Comment: thanks sir,yes, its was giving error for that `request` in that line, but can i know why it was raising error?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: why would you need a request when constructing a `User`? It expects column data. Furthermore you forgot to add a *hashed* password. You will need to find a way to hash the password.